# Comparing collision energy formats in the NIST 17 MS/MS library

Tags: mass-spectrometry

In the NIST 17 MS/MS library, collision energy can be represented as a positive integer (i.e. 1,2,3,...), a percentage (i.e. 35%), or a floating point number (i.e. 7.3 eV). How can I compare these different collision energy settings? Is it possible to convert them all to eV, for example?